# Twilio Redirect From Webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

I've been trying to redirect incoming phone calls from Twilio via webhook to execute TwiML hosted on a website.

For testing, I've been using 'raw' GitHub to host my XML as a 'GET' request webhook.

My code is in the format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>
            +447xxxxxxxxx
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

When I run this code from a TwiML bin, it redirects as I want, however when I send it through a webhook, it just says the phone number out loud.

Any help on why this is would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the MIME type the web server is returning.

You can find more details here.

[Twilio understands MIME types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types)

The webserver is returning `text/plain` instead of `text/xml`.

You can host your static TwiML in a [TwiMl Bin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! That makes a lot of sense! Out of interest, would you know how to designate mime types on static html pages?

Comment: It is a setting handled by the server, and each server handles it differently so really difficult to say. Specific to github, I found this but haven't tried it - https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#mime-types-on-github-pages.